# ArcServer creates additional jobs

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, certificate-authority, backup

We're running CA ARCserve Backup r12.5 (Build 5854) - Small Business Server Edition on our Small Business Server 2008.
There is a daily job which saves the systemdrive, exchange and 3 databases to our backup storage.

It seems like this daily job creates these additional jobs every time it runs.
I don't know why it's doing this. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

(I'm sorry this screenshot is in german... "Ergänzungsjob" means something like "extensionjob" or "additionjob")

[image: the original job and a few of the additional jobs]

**Edit**:
Forgot to tell you:
This job is configured to do a full backup. There is no rotation configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be Makeup jobs. These indicate that your backup has not been successful. You need to look at the logs to find out why the Sichern Mo-Fr job is failing.